# slonik - Unexpected value expression

Tags: slonik

I am using slonik lib to run that query
`connection` of DatabaseTransactionConnectionType

```
const fileIds = ["3001"];
const noteId = 424;

 const query = sql`
  UPDATE file SET note_id = ${noteId}
  WHERE file_id in (${fileIds})`;
 await connection.maybeOne(query);
```

but I got that exception

```
TypeError: Unexpected value expression
```

any idea whats wrong in my query

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
const query = sql`
  UPDATE file SET note_id = ${noteId} WHERE id IN (${sql.valueList(fileIds)})`;
```